# Graphical representation of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

For the given function:
$$
f(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &  \text{if}\ z = 0\\ 
 \frac{{}\bar{{z}}}{z} & \text{if}\ z\neq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

How would I prove that $ f(z) $ is continuous for all of at the point where $z=0$?

My thoughts:

You would have to show that the limit as $z$ approaches $0$ is equal to $1$. How would I go about doing this? Would the Cauchy-Riemann Equations be the best approach for this type of question?

Comment: I cannot see anything regarding graphical representation in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Riemann equations provide us with a necessary condition for the differentiability of a function. Whereas to check the continuity of a function (say) $f$ at some point $z_0$ you just need to check the following 3 conditions:

(1) $f$ is defined at the point $z_0$

(2) $\lim _{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists

(3) $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)=f(z_0)$

Now comming to your question, condition (1) is satisfied by $f$ in the problem. To compute the value of the limit you can convert the function into polar form.

i.e. Take  $z=re^{i\theta}$ and letting $r\to 0$

$$lim_{r\to 0}\frac{re^{-i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}=e^{-2i\theta}$$

Now since the limit value is different for different choices of $\theta$, the above limit does not exist.

i.e $\lim _{z\to 0} f(z)$ does not exists

Hence, the condition (2) is not satisfied and we can thus conclude that $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$

Comment: Would that no imply that the limit when z approaches zero is equal to zero, not one?

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided a complete solution to your question. @LlewyThomas